# PHP myadmin not working after Varnish Install

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04, varnish

I know this is not exactly a programming question, but I hope someone could help me out. I have installed Varnish accelerator for PHP; ports were changed during the installation.
After the successful installation I can access my site in my document root. But 'phpmyadmin' can not connect to the mysql server.

Comment: Do your PHP pages still work? is mysql still running? what errors can you find in your error logs?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine including mysql. There is nothing in the error logs about mysql, varnish or phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

Just pass your phpmyadmin app through a cache, something like

```
sub vcl_recv {
..
if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
return(pass);
}
..
}
```

OR

```
sub vcl_recv {
..
if (req.http.host == "pma.yourdomain.com") {
return(pass);
}
..
}
```

Comment: I get an error message saying: 

Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
('input' Line 153 Pos 1)
..
#-

Running VCC-compiler failed

Comment: It is not an error from my example. Could you please show your config?

Comment: This is the link to the config file http://ec2-184-73-117-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com/default.vcl.txt

Comment: It is default varnish configuration and it not caching anything. So, your problem is outside of Varnish

Answer (score 1):

in sub vcl_fetch add

```
if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
return (hit_for_pass);
}
```

and in config.inc.php add

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin/';
```